# Celery in virtualenv with supervisor

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

supervisor install in Linux Ubuntu with python2.7

virtualenv：python3.6 + Django2.0 + celery4.2

this is celery.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'savemoney.settings')
app = Celery('savemoney')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init** file :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

My celery worker in local is well, but when I run Celery in virtual with supervisor:

```
  File "/path/env/mysite/mysite/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/path/env/mysite/mysite/celery.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
TypeError: config_from_object() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'
```

My celery worker setting:

```
[program:celery.worker] 

directory=/path/env/mysite/

command=/path/env/mysite/celery -A mysite worker -l info
user=root

numprocs=1          
autostart=true      
autorestart=true    
stopsignal=INT
stdout_logfile=/path/env/mysite/celery_worker.log 
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB  
stdout_logfile_backups=10     
 redirect_stderr=false         
stderr_logfile=/path/env/mysite/celery_worker_err.log 
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB 
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

I tryed :

1.environment

```
environment=PATH="/path/env/bin",VIRTUAL_ENV="/path/env/mysite/",PYTHONPATH="/path/env/lib/python:/path/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
```

2.command full_path

```
command=/path/env/mysite/celery -A mysite worker -l info
```

supervisor> status

```
supervisor> status
celery.work                      BACKOFF   can't find command '/path/env/mysite/celery'
```

I refer to someone else's path like this:

```
command=/path/env/mysite/bin/celery -A mysite worker -l info
```

but my project is no "bin" directory

I tried:

```
command=/path/env/bin/celery -A mysite worker -l info
```

the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Comment: Can you share your `celery.py` file? Are you sure the version of celery you are using is 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is using celery 4.2 with supervisor

I solved the problem by using celery 3.1.16